# Libreoffice writer: Alignment of paste special HTML

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer, I want to copy over some columns from Calc. I want to copy over exactly how they look, and I've found that paste special HTML brings them over exactly how I'd like them, since I need the rows to break over pages when they need to.

However, I can't get the table which copies over aligned. It automatically aligns to the left, and I've tried a number of ways to highlight the table and align it all to no avail.

Does anybody know how I can change the alignment of the tables please?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Copy from Calc.

[image: copy]

2. Paste special as HTML in Writer.  It helps to show table boundaries: `View -> Table Boundaries`.

[image: paste]

3. Select the table by clicking in the table, then `Table -> Select -> Table`.

[image: select]

4. `Format -> Align -> Center`.

[image: center]